# Problem involving lenses and mirrors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reflection, refraction, geometric-optics, lenses

A biconvex lens of focal length 15 cm is in front of a plane mirror. The distance
between the lens and the mirror is 10 cm. A small object is kept at a distance of 30 cm
from the lens. The final image is

a) virtual and at a distance of 16 cm from the mirror

b) real and at a distance of 16 cm from the mirror

c) virtual and at a distance of 20 cm from the mirror

d) real and at a distance of 20 cm from the mirror

I tried to work out the problem and I found the answer to be that the final image is formed at 10cm to the left of the lens after refraction through the lens and reflection by the mirror.  So the correct answer according to me is option D. But the solution suggests that the correct option is B.

Comment: Did you try to draw the setup and some possible solution?

Comment: Try to draw a ray-diagram for your setup and pay careful attention to how the rays reflect and refract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint Object is at 2F so the image will also be at  2F but there is a mirror placed in between so this will create an image beyond the plane mirror will act as imaginary object and that will create a real image.